# Is the ENI detached from an Amazon EC2 instance when it is stopped and started?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc

Does ENI gets detached when we stop and start the EC2 instance which is connected to the VPC in AWS?

Answer (score 9):

An ENI (Elastic Network Interface) is **never detached** when an instance is Stopped.

Every Amazon EC2 instance has a **primary ENI** on `eth0`. This ENI cannot be detached from the instance.

It is also possible to create **secondary ENIs** and attach them to instances. These stay attached during a Stop and Start, but you can choose to detach it and then attach it to another instance.

I notice that your question is very similar to a [sample question](https://awstrainingandcertification.s3.amazonaws.com/production/AWS_certified_solutions_architect_associate_examsample.pdf) for the **AWS Solutions Architect - Associate** exam:

> **Which of the following will occur when an EC2 instance in a VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) with an associated Elastic IP is stopped and started? (Choose 2 answers)**
>
> A. The Elastic IP will be dissociated from the instance
>
> B. All data on instance-store devices will be lost
>
> C. All data on EBS (Elastic Block Store) devices will be lost
>
> D. The ENI (Elastic Network Interface) is detached
>
> E. The underlying host for the instance is changed

In this case, the question is referring to an **Elastic IP** address rather than an ENI. Elastic IP addresses remain attached to an instance during Stop and Start if the instance is in a VPC. Earlier-style instances launched under **EC2 Classic**, however, do have their Elastic IP address detached when Stopped.

Answer (score 0):

If you just stop the instance you will not detach the Elastic IP. All properties of the instance remain (If you log into the AWS console you can view the description of the instance, it keeps all its properties)

so if you start again a stopped instance all its network interface are just as before and you can access the instance by the same private/public IP as before

If you terminate though the ec2 instance, it is detached automatically - When you terminate the instance, AWS will ask you if you want to release the network interface (as an interface that is not associated occurs cost) you can still keep this interface if you plan to recreate an instance and re-associate the interface but it will not be in use

Answer (score -1):

B & E

- The Elastic IP will be dissociated from the instance – x The instance retains its associated Elastic IP addresses.
- **All data on instance-store devices will be lost -/ data stored in the RAM of the host computer or the instance store volumes of the host computer is gone.**
- All data on EBS (Elastic Block Store) devices will be lost – x EBS Volume remains attached to the instance, and their data persists.
- The ENI (Elastic Network Interface) is detached – x An ENI (Elastic Network Interface) is never detached when an instance is Stopped.
- **The underlying host for the instance is changed -/ – In most cases, the instance is migrated to a new underlying host computer when it's started.**